# LanguageExt - "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" in Either.Match

Tags: c#, language-ext

This is a follow-up to [a question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202321/how-do-i-conditionally-call-code-when-using-languageext-with-query-syntax), but is (I think) much simpler, so I'm asking it separately. To clarify the question, I've stripped this one down even further.

The code here uses the `Language-Ext` Nuget package.

The only data structure needed here is the following...

```cs
record Trans(int Id, decimal Amount)
```

I have a (very much simplified) method that calls an external service to approve a transaction...

```cs
static async Task<Either<int, string>> CallService(Trans transaction) =>
  transaction.Amount < 1.5M
    ? "Success"
    : -1;
```

I want to call this as part of code like this (again, very much simplified)...

```cs
static async Task<Either<int, string>> ApproveRefund(Trans transaction) =>
  await (
    from result in CallService(transaction).ToAsync()
    select result
  )
  .Match(result => result, s => s);
```

However, I get a compiler error "*Error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*" on the two lambdas I pass to the `Match` method.

I can't work out what I've done wrong here. Anyone able to help? Thanks

Comment: What does that LINQ query do? A [mcve] would make it much easier to help you. My *guess* is that the precedence of `await` vs `.` is confusing things, but without more details it's hard to know.

Comment: @JonSkeet That is actually an MRE, I copied it directly out of LinqPad. The Linq query is a very short version of one that gathers various bits of data, optionally calls the external service (mocked here by `CallService`) and then saves the data (not shown). A fuller explanation is found in the other question. I didn't repeat it all here as I didn't think it relevant. My guess is that this is a syntax issue, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @JonSkeet Also, please can you clarify what you meant about the precedence of `await` vs `.` as I'm not clear. I've done queries like this many times before and not had this issue. Thanks

Comment: No, that's definitely *not* an MRE. Where is `Either` declared, for example? What about `Match`? Note that while LinqPad is a great tool, it's not a good idea to assume that everyone who might answer your question will have access to it. If you can provide a console app which folks can copy/paste/compile/run, you'll make it easier for far more people to help you. (I'd rather not go into the details of my speculation around precedence until I've actually got something I can check.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I assumed that the presence of the `language-ext` tag, and its mention in the title made it clear enough that I was using that Package. I'll update the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need to be more explicit with the return types...

```cs
.Match(Right<int, string>, Left<int, string>);
```

I'm not actually sure why you need to do this, but I have hit this issue occasionally, and this fixed it.

Maybe one of the experts can explain why, but that should get you going.

Comment: Well cut off both my legs and call me Shorty! Why oh why would you need to do that? Thanks very much again

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I just updated the code to be a little more concise